# Adding a Jquery onclick event to all links within a certain class

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors, onclick

How do I add a Jquery onclick event that looks for any link like the below so it needs to be in a td and have a class of "rightImage"

```
  <td class="rightImage"><a href="somelink.aspx"><img src="someimage.jpg"alt=""></a></td>
```

The click event needs to be:

```
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'sidebanner', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),o,true]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.` to target class in jQuery and use **[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** to handle click event:

```
$('td.rightImage a').click(function() {
     // Your code here
});
```

If your `td` have been added dynamically (added after page load), you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$("body").on("click", "td.rightImage a", function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: He wanted the link to be on the anchor, so I suggest it should rather be `$('td.rightImage a').click(function() { // Your code here });`

Comment: I tried both of these but I'm getting an error in my console :/

Comment: this info about dynamic load was remarkable

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
$(".rightImage").click(function(){
  //do something necessary here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
$('td.rightImage a').click(function(){
    ...
});
```

(like in css for selectors)

but your tag  needs to be in a table, otherwise it will not work